# NullPointerException thrown in where it can't be thrown

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, apache-spark

I get a NullPointerException in a piece of code which can't throw it.
I start thinking to have found a bug in JRE. I am using javac 1.8.0_51 as compiler, and the problem occurs both in jre 1.8.0_45 and the latest 1.8.0_60.

The line throwing the exception is inside a loop, which is inside a closure lambda function. We are running such closure in spark 1.4.
The line is executed 1-2 million times, and I get the error not deterministically, with the same input, once every 3 or 4 run.

I'm pasting relevant piece of code here:

```
        JavaRDD .... mapValues(iterable -> {
                LocalDate[] dates = ...
                long[] dateDifferences = ...

                final double[] fooArray = new double[dates.length];
                final double[] barArray = new double[dates.length];
                for (Item item : iterable) {
                    final LocalDate myTime = item.getMyTime();
                    final int largerIndex = ...
                    if (largerIndex == 0) {
                        ...
                    } else if (largerIndex >= dates.length - 1) {
                        ...
                    } else {
                        final LocalDate largerDate = dates[largerIndex];
                        final long daysBetween = ...
                        if (daysBetween == 0) {
                            ...
                        } else {
                            double factor = ...
                            // * * * NULL POINTER IN NEXT LINE * * * //
                            fooArray[largerIndex - 1] += item.getFoo() * factor;
                            fooArray[largerIndex] += item.getFoo() * (1 - factor);
                            barArray[largerIndex - 1] += item.getBar() * factor;
                            barArray[largerIndex] += item.getBar() * (1 - factor);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new NewItem(fooArray, barArray);
            })
            ...
```

I started analysing code and found that:

- fooArray is never null since you have "new" few lines above
- largerIndex is primitive
- item is never null as it is already used few lines above
- getFoo() returns double with no unboxing
- factor is primitive

I can't run the same input locally and debug it: this is run on a spark cluster. So I added some debug println before the throwing line:

```
System.out.println("largerIndex: " + largerIndex);
System.out.println("foo: " + Arrays.toString(foo));
System.out.println("foo[1]: " + foo[1]);
System.out.println("largerIndex-1: " + (largerIndex-1));
System.out.println("foo[largerIndex]: " + foo[largerIndex]);
System.out.println("foo[largerIndex - 1]: " + foo[largerIndex - 1]);
```

And this is the output:

```
largerIndex: 2
foo: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
foo[1]: 0.0
largerIndex-1: 1
foo[largerIndex]: 0.0
15/10/01 12:36:11 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 17162, host13): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.class.lambda$mymethod$87560622$1(MyFile.java:150)
    at my.other.class.$$Lambda$306/764841389.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1027)
    ...
```

So *foo[largerIndex - 1]* is currently throwing the null-pointer. Note that also the following throws it:

```
int idx = largerIndex - 1;
foo[idx] += ...;
```

But not the following:

```
foo[1] += ....;
```

I gave a look at bytecode in class file and found nothing strange. You correctly have the reference to foo and largerIndex in the stack before iconst_1, isub, and daload.

I'm just posting this to collect ideas before thinking to a jre bug.
Does anyone of you experienced same class of problems using spark? or lambda function in general. Is it possible to run jvm with some debug flag to help me understand this strange behavior? Or should I file the issue to someone somewhere?

Comment: *I get a NullPointerException in a piece of code which can't throw it*. IMO the line seems a good candidate for a `NPE`. How do you populate `iterable`? for what you explain seems more a data transfer or integrity problem.

Comment: Why don't you think that the code can throw NPE? The fact that it does should be an indication, if not proof that it indeed can throw NPE.

Comment: Does the *body* of `getFoo()` potentially throw an NPE? Please show us that. It may be that the stack trace has omitted some inlined code, or something like that.

Comment: Also please replace `for (Item item : iterable)` with `for (final Item item : iterable)`.

Comment: @jonskeet: getFoo(), as I said, returns a double with no unboxing. For the other: please read more carefully the whole post. Throwing statement is foo[largerIndex-1], with largerIndex-1 = 1, while foo[1] is not throwing it.

Comment: add `assert fooArray[largerIndex - 1]!=null && item!=null` before the line that throws NPE. Add an assert in getFoo before each and every use of a reference, if any. Enable assertions. What are the results of that?

Comment: You've said it returns a double with no unboxing, but that doesn't say anything about what *else* it does. For example, your description would still be true for `return point.getX() * point.getY();` - but *that* could throw a `NullPointerException`, without any unboxing being involved.

Comment: Given that you can provoke the error reasonably reliably though non-deterministically, can you try to gradually reduce the amount of code involved, to try to pinpoint where the problem is? If we can get to the stage where we can reproduce it too, it would be easier to help you. Are you able to try the same code under different platforms?

Comment: @jonskeet: ok sorry, it's just a no-logic getter: "double getFoo() { return foo; }"

Comment: You said - " *So foo[largerIndex - 1] is currently throwing the null-pointer.*" .. Pretty, strange, it can potentially throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but not NPE. NPE can only be thrown if you so something like - `Integer integer = null; int[] ints = new int[2]; ints[integer] += 1;` but you are using primitives, so I don't see any chance. Probably try to look for other perspective or just a try - use NULL check for `item` in `ooArray[largerIndex - 1] += item.getFoo() * factor;` .. I would agree with @JonSkeet you need to decompose it such that we can reproduce it ..

Comment: @hagrawal: No, it could throw an NPE if `fooArray` were null... but earlier we've proved that it isn't. Likewise the fact that the call to `item.getMyTime()` doesn't fail proves that `item` is non-null, assuming it really is an instance method, and that `item` isn't reassigned within the loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, but it is deterministic that `fooArray` is not NULL. What is non-deterministic is that `item` could be NULL at that point because OP has not shown us complete code, it could be possible that some part of code between `item.getMyTime()` and `item.getFoo()` could be making it NULL. Otherwise I don't see any chance of NPE in array access .. Also, his stack trace is logging it as WARN, I don't know how to take it ..

Comment: Pretty hard to decompose. Run involves a lot of data and time. Anyway I would prefer to enable some debug flag that can make jvm print stack state and which opcode in class file cause NPE.. if any is existing

Comment: @hagrawal: Well the OP has already stated in the question that he's tried to isolate everywhere it could logically happen. That's the point - we can't reasonably dismiss anything, given that what's happening appears to be impossible.

Comment: Also note that it is not a matter of founding a solution. We already re-write it reassembling group-map-reduce chain and the error went away (with almost same piece of relevant code). I'm just attracted by jvm unexpected behavoir, and similar experiences with spark environment

Comment: Given that fact that we are not able to reproduce at our end, I would suggest enable more loggers so that you can nail the exact thing and also see the values just before our NPE .. I know you had said that `foo[largerIndex - 1] ` is throwing NPE but it is unconvincing for me given the data you have provided ..  `System.out.println(fooArray);System.out.println(largerIndex);System.out.println(item);System.out.println(item.getFoo());System.out.println(factor);System.out.println(item.getFoo() * factor);`

Comment: Is it possible that there is some bytecode rewriting going on near this code ... so that the code that is actually being run is significantly different to what the source code shows?

Comment: If you are going to submit this as a JRE bug report, you will need to include an complete example that they can use to reproduce the problem.  Bugs that can't be reproduced are easy to dismiss.

Comment: @StephenC: I don't know how spark handles closure transfer to executors. I don't think there is bytecode rewriting, but I can't be sure

Comment: Can you confirm that it is that specific line that causes the exception? As in, if you rearrange the the order that largerIndex and largerIndex-1 get set, does it still only throw the NPE only when setting fooArray at  largerIndex-1? If not, then getFoo() must be the culprit.

Comment: @jason9187: I confirm. Wherever i move fooArray[largerIndex-1], only and always there, I get NPE

Comment: @Jack : I would then try only printing the values (read), then assigning them constant values (write). If those both work, then the problem would be what you're setting them to.

Comment: @jason9187: note that the problem originally arose during an assignment, but then also within a println(), that is by reading it. Also, note that fooArray[1] is accessed correctly, fooArray[largerIndex-1], with largerIndex=2 throws NPE.

Comment: But largerIndex is a primitive, so you cannot be getting the NPE from its reference, and you would get OutOfBounds if improperly accessing the array. Therefore, you are saying that fooArray is somehow null?

Comment: @jason9187. I am saying that this is an unexpected behavior and that it is probably a bug. I would love to receive info about how to behave in this case, given that I can't easily isolate (and submit) code to reproduce the problem

Comment: Does this code throw NPE on JVM in interpreted mode?

Comment: @VladimirKorenev thanks for the hint. I didn't know such option. I'll try it and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me like it is a very similar problem to the one described here (a JIT problem):
http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com.br/2014/11/but-thats-impossible-or-finding-out.html

Your observation, that it does not occur every time and that it is "impossible" to occur when reading the code is exactly the same as described there.
To find it out, use the commandline options to exclude your method from being JIT'ed like (you need to specify the correct Class/method name):

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,java/lang/String.indexOf
```

Or by switching it off completely using

```
-Xint
```

which may be too drastic.

Comment: Thanks to all people who tried to help, but unfortunately I'm not able to perform suggested changes anymore. We moved forward with code and error went away automagically. I accept this answer as it would probably solve the problem